# PL/SQL error : 'CC' <cursor variable name> is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have tons of experience with T-SQL but I am new to PL/SQL.

What is wrong with my loop below?

Simple thing... I have a SP which has an OUT cursor parameter.
I am just trying to call it and print out the records returned in that OUT param.

But I get the error saying:

> 'CC' is not a procedure or is undefined

```
DECLARE
  cc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN 
  TEST_001
  (
    CUR => cc,
    d => 1
  );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('DONE');

  FOR rec in cc
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.OK); 
  END LOOP;

END;
```

If I comment out my `FOR` loop then it works fine,
but I cannot see what I got in that cursor from the SP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PLS-00221: 'C1'(cursor) is not a procedure or is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292451/pls-00221-c1cursor-is-not-a-procedure-or-is-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cc` is a ref cursor, which isn't the same as a standard cursor. You can't use a `for <record> in <cursor> loop` construct with a ref cursor.

You need to fetch from the ref cursor into a variable (or multiple variables depending on what the cursor query in the procedure is doing) of the right data type, which you can do in a loop, exiting when the result set from the ref cursor is exhausted:

```
DECLARE
  cc SYS_REFCURSOR;
  result VARCHAR2(10); -- or whatever is appropriate
BEGIN 
  TEST_001
  (
    CUR => cc, 
    d => 1
  );

  LOOP
    FETCH cc INTO result;
    EXIT WHEN cc%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(result); 
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I've used a single `result` variable and guessed a data type; you'll need one for each column expression in the actual query. Or you can define a record type with one field per column expression; say if the cursor query has two:

```
DECLARE
  cc SYS_REFCURSOR;
  TYPE rec_type IS RECORD (
    ok VARCHAR2(10), -- or whatever is appropriate
    other NUMBER     -- or whatever is appropriate
  );
  rec rec_type;
BEGIN 
  TEST_001
  (
    CUR => cc, 
    d => 1
  );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('DONE');

  LOOP
    FETCH cc INTO rec;
    EXIT WHEN cc%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.ok); 
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

If the cursor query is doing `select *` from a single table you could also use its `%ROWTYPE` instead of defining your own record type.

If you don't know the structure that will be in the ref cursor in advance then you're getting into the world of dynamic SQL and the `dbms_sql` package, which is rather more complicated.

Comment: It's static stuff, no dynamic SQL. Thanks a lot.